# Is there somewhere a guide to SBT for non-Scala programmers?

Tags: scala, operators, sbt

Someday, I'd like to learn Scala. What I see about the language from people who like it is very encouraging.

Today, though, is not that day. Today, I'd just like to make some changes to my team's build file. Unfortunately, this build file was put together with SBT, and is nearly incomprehensible.

My main issue is that it appears to me that SBT introduces some huge collection of new operators that do things with strings and lists to create some sort of sbt object.  For example, in sbt:

```
"args4j" % "args4j" % "2.0.12"
```

Apparently is actually defined; however, I can't even tell what type it is at the `scala` repl, since at the repl I get the sensible error:

```
scala> val tstcrap = "args4j" % "args4j" % "2.0.12"
<console>:6: error: value % is not a member of java.lang.String
       val tstcrap = "args4j" % "args4j" % "2.0.12"
```

I get this error even after setting up the classpath to include the `sbt-launch.jar` file and doing `import sbt._`.

Likewise, I'm dealing with stuff like this:

```
 val jarSources = (descendents(classesOutput ##, "*") ---
                  assemblyExclude(classesOutput ##))
```

What's that `##` operator, what's that `---` doing, and more importantly what is the type of this expression? Are all these new operators documented somewhere, and is there some way to get a scala repl that's using the same language as is used in the sbt build files?

Looking at this `sbt` file reminds me of trying to decipher `perl` without ever reading any of the relevant man pages. (Not a recommended activity)

**Update**: After looking at the links in the answer below, and looking at other questions and answers tagged `sbt`, I've come across the major piece of scala knowledge that I was missing: scala allows one to define implicit conversions that will be invoked before methods are resolved. In this case, `sbt` defines inside the `ManagedProject` trait, an implicit conversion from `String` to the private class `sbt.GroupID`, so that

```
"a" % "b"
```

Is really something like

```
(new GroupID("a")) % "b"
```

I imagine the resolution order and other rules around implicit conversions must get very complicated; it almost reminds me of the nightmares you can introduce in C++ with operator overloading when done through non-member functions.

Comment: Here are some hints: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Index

Comment: Actually, implicit rules are little different than scope rules -- what you define, what's in the same package, what you have imported, what is defined in a class, what that class inherits, just like scope. Add to that, companion object to static type, companion object to expected type, and companion objects to type parameters. SBT is not "Hello, World". A configuration can be written easily, given the SBT tutorial. Understanding _how_ SBT works, however, is no easier than understanding how Maven or Gradle or Ivy or Ant or Buildr work.

Comment: By the way, indicate what version of SBT. SBT up to 0.7.7 is one thing, but SBT from recently released 0.10.0 onwards can be very different.

Comment: A `mimimi` for triple minus instead of `---` would look more like a method name than an operator, without being more clear. And implicit conversions aren't far away - in the actual file, or in an imported one, nearly as easy to find, as `super.mimimi (...)`.

Comment: operator overloading is back :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since an SBT build file is a full-fledged Scala source file and relies on some libraries provided by SBT itself, it's difficult to cover SBT well without relying on some familiarity with Scala. I'm not aware of such a guide.

For the specific questions you raise, I think these wiki pages will help:

- `%` operator for strings: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement
- `##` and `---` operators: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Paths

If you want to get a Scala REPL running with the SBT libraries available, try this:

```
$ sbt console-project
```

Some other useful commands are listed at http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt .

Comment: I'd like an updated answer to this question. I have no idea where in the current docs '<<=' is for example.

Comment: Those Google Code links are dead. Go to [the GitHub project](https://github.com/sbt/sbt) now.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2016 (5 years later).
This is not a *complete* guide, but the article "[Sbt heiroglyphs and multi-projects explained](https://medium.com/from-the-couch/sbt-heiroglyphs-and-multi-projects-explained-ee0aef3efdce#.fme03erbj)" from [Divan Visagie](https://twitter.com/DivanVisagie) can help starting to use `sbt`.

Plus, [the `sbt` documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html) is quite complete nowadays, and covers [multiple projects in a single build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html).
The ['---' operator is described in the PathFinder](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Paths.html) (since [the 0.2 version](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Older-Changes.html)).